# CakePHP - do defined associations affect performance if they're not being used?

Tags: cakephp

In a CakePHP project, during `bake`, I put all possible associations between models, now I want to clean up my code and delete the ones that are not necessary, but, on other hand, if I accidentally delete something that is being used, what could cause a new error that should be fixed?

So, the question is, if I have some associations defined between models, whether it is `belongsTo`, `hasMany`or `hasAndBelongsToMany`, does this in some way effect performance, considering that I am always using `Containable` and for each query, I specify the exact models and fields that I require?

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. I actually ran into an issue because of this.

Cake loads the models immediately associated by the current model.

Take the example: `Trunk hasMany Branch hasMany Leaf`

Assuming you're working with the Trunk model, Cake will load the Trunk and Branch models. Loading a model only does a *describe* call to the database which is then cached. No searches are performed on the database outside of the scope of your `->find` call.

This caused an issue for me. If you have one form and want to add a Trunk, Branch and Leaf all at once, the formHelper won't know the format of the fields in Leaf because the model isn't loaded. In this case use `$this->loadModel` to load the model manually.

Comment: Actually I didn't use bake, this might add $this->loadModel for you if required.